# Could you create the "miller" tag

Tags: support, tags

[Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is a great cli tool to work with structured text data file.

The tag description could be:

> Miller is an open source command line utility: it is like awk, sed, cut, join, and sort for name-indexed data such as CSV, TSV, and tabular JSON.

Comment: The first question is how many questions we have that needs the tag applying to them. Without anything to attach the tag to then it will simply be cleaned up and deleted.

Comment: At a [quick glance](https://superuser.com/search?q=miller) I can only see one question that might be worth putting the tag on, the rest seem to be proper names such as Aaron Miller, Keith Miller and others who could be program authors. No point in making the tag just for that. If you want the tag creating are you willing to write a better tag excerpt and info page for it similar to https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel/info? We [don't just want to copy and paste information](https://superuser.com/help/tag-excerpts) from whatever website maintains it, as is your current suggestion.

Comment: Any question that was about this tool could easily just be tagged (json and/or csv), we don't need a tag, for a specific community tool (there are far to many to do that).

Comment: Simple: Ask a user with 1500 reputation (maybe in [chat](http://chat.superuser.com)) to make it.

Comment: I'm not allowed to suggest edits, so could someone else change the annoying horizontal scrolling to a standard block-quote.  Plus remove the "thank you".

Comment: @RayButterworth - You absolutely have the capability of proposing an edit they just have to be approved.  If you see something that should be improved you should propose the edit not wait for someone else to do it

Comment: @Ramhound, For me, the `Edit` button produces a large red banner: "*Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.*".

Answer (score 1):

Unless the tool gains a large amount of popularity and becomes as common as [awk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/awk) or [sed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sed) I'm going to say that for now we don't *need* the tag.

We shouldn't create a tag just because a named tool exists, especially when there are better and more relevant tags, as suggested by Ramhound in a comment, of [json](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/json) and [csv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/csv).

Unless it gets to a point where someone *has* to use Miller to achieve something, and we have a lot of questions where *only* Miller is the answer, or we are getting a lot of questions about it then the specific tag serves no real purpose except separating questions from their more general audience who could suggest different ways with other tools.

From a [quick search](https://superuser.com/search?q=miller) I can see perhaps two questions that might be worth tagging. That's not really enough for me to consider it worthwhile.

At an absolute minimum we want the excerpt to be more than just [copy-pasted information from the tool website](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller). From our review queue rejection reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://superuser.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.